# Get all images from a div ID and add links

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am having some difficulties building a javascript that gets all the images from a div ID, and add a link to the big image on each of the thumbnails. Here is my code.

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script>
        function addGallery(){
            var getDivId = document.getElementById("imgContainer");
            var images = getDivId.getElementsByTagName("img").innerHTML;
            for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
                getDivId.innerHtml = "<a id='g2Image' href='big/" + images[i].src + "'>" + images[i].src + "</a>";
            }
        }    
    </script>
 </head>
 <body onload='addGallery()'>
 <div id="imgContainer">
 <img src="/images/galleries/img1.jpg" alt="" width="125" height="100" />
 <img src="/images/galleries/img1.jpg" alt="" width="125" height="100" />
 <img src="/images/galleries/img1.jpg" alt="" width="125" height="100" />
 <img src="/images/galleries/img1.jpg" alt="" width="125" height="100" />
 <img src="/images/galleries/img1.jpg" alt="" width="125" height="100" />
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Thank you in advance!
Regards.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this in Javascript? When I have done things like this before, it's because I lack access to the server-side development environment. After reading through this, it seems like it might be cleaner to do this on the server side (if possible.)

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning innerHTML in each loop without concatenating the existing HTML.

Change:

```
getDivId.innerHTML = "<a id='g2Image' href='big/" + images[i].src + "'>" + images[i].src + "</a>";
```

to

```
getDivId.innerHTML += "<a id='g2Image' href='big/" + images[i].src + "'>" + images[i].src + "</a>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Um... you're actually attempting to grab an object property from an array, which doesn't exist:

```
var images = getDivId.getElementsByTagName("img").innerHTML;
```

Should be changed to:

```
var images = getDivId.getElementsByTagName("img");
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Edit 2

Note than in IE, the `image.src` value will be the full path of the image so you can't just prepend 'big/' to them.

#### Edit

Oops, didn't see that you were adding A elements. Presumably you want the images to be inside the link. Instead of innerHTML, you can use DOM methods to creat the links:

```
function addGallery(){

    var getDivId = document.getElementById("imgContainer");
    var path = '/images/galleries/';
    var images = toArray(getDivId.getElementsByTagName("img"));

    var oA = document.createElement('a');
    var a, image, parent;

    for(var i=0, iLen=images.length; i<iLen; i++) {
        image = images[i];
        a = oA.cloneNode(false);
        a.href = image.src.replace(path, '/big' + path);
        image.parentNode.appendChild(a);
        a.appendChild(image);
    }
}

function toArray(a) {
  var result = [];
  var i = a.length;
  while (i--) {
    result[i] = a[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

There is also a [document.images collection](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-90379117) that is all the images in the document, but likely you only want those in the div.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your answer (and attempting to not be a jerk about it)... He has to modify the DOM (or use a straight JS event), since he's attempting to add an anchor on top of the images that already exist.  Really, this should be done server-side, but I think we can ignore that for now.

Comment: Sorry, missed the added links part—answer updated. Yes, should be a server-side thing but sometimes people have to try stuff client side before they get the point. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I added now the link to each image, but I need to add a id and onclick event on each link, so I am stuck again...

About the server-side solution, that would be great, if this wasn't a hosted CMS and no access to add php code. Anyway, if there is a better solution in PHP, whould you mind to expose that for us?

Regards!